# jQuery get() serverResponse not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery

I have a small .get() that receives a block of HTML from a php file (the file renders the code so that it will pass as plain HTML). All of the code is coming in, but it isn't behaving as I had expected.

I'm using Yahoo Tabview, and if I copy and paste the same HTML code into the HTML section of my .html file, everything is shows up and tabs correctly, but when I bring it in through the .get() function all the code is applied to every tab's content area.

Here's my .get() function:

```
$.get('index.php', function (serverResponse) {
    $('.yui-content').append(serverResponse);
});
```

Does jQuery add anything to the code or cause it to act differently that if you copy-and-paste it into the file?

Let me know if I need to include any other code...

Comment: The HTML would be usefull, but I think the problem is the class name in the callback. Change it to use the tab ID. Your code is getting all elements with the class of `yuy-content` and putting data into them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you are using a class selector - which I assume is on more than one element. I can't give you a definitive answer without seeing your HTML, but if you change the jQuery `append()` to use an Id selector (example below), it should work correctly.

```
$.get('index.php', function (serverResponse) {
    $('#first-tab').append(serverResponse);
});
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, something like `.yui-content:last` or `.yui-content:first`, depending on your needs.

Comment: Actually the entire HTML block is coded so that it can land right in .yui-content and everything should work properly. There's only one .yui-content div. the div's that correspond with the tabs are called .content

Comment: I've got it working. Just made a dumb mistake and added a # in the actual id names, so once I took that out it works perfectly. Of course, I needed to see your answer to get my brain working that way so thanks!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , hey man, I'm having trouble with this again. My jQuery trip has taken me all over and now I'm back to the ajax request. I have this code: `$.get('http://www.triadbarspecials.com/ws/index.php', function(html){ $('#page').append(html); });` The #page is a page div with that ID. Think you can help?

Comment: @Justin unless `triadbarspecials.com` is your domain, that won't work. You can only make AJAX requests to your own domain, unless you use `JSONP` format.

Comment: it's my domain, and i'm calling the file from the same domain. everything I've researched says this code should work, so I'm thinking maybe it's got something to do with how I render the page that I'm calling. here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLxfq/)

Comment: Have a look in the console for any errors. You're best to open a new question for this though, so that more people can see it.